# How to return the sum of friends_count?

Tags: sql, postgresql

`properties` is an hstore column.

Im listing all entries of each user, and only showing the most recent `friends_count`, hence why I need to group by `user_id` first and do an `array_agg` with an `ORDER BY`.

Now, I'd like to return the total sum of all `friends_count`. So in this case, only one row with 4.

```
SELECT user_id,
  to_json((array_agg(properties -> 'friends_count' ORDER BY id DESC))[1]::int) AS friends_count
FROM daily_statistics st
GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY max(id) DESC;
```

Result:

```
 user_id | friends_count
---------+---------
     549 | 2
      16 | 2
(2 rows)
```

Comment: If I remove `GROUP BY` how do i get the most recent entry from a user?

Comment: "So in this case, only one row with 4." --- in your question you have nothing about most recent entry

Comment: If I don't group by, I would be counting the `friends_count` column of a user more than once, assuming the same user has more than one entry

Comment: what will be the user_id in your output table when frind_count = 4 or you need only friend_count?

Comment: No `user_id`, I just want the sum

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT SUM(friends_count) AS total_friend_counts
    FROM
      (SELECT user_id,
              to_json((array_agg(properties -> 'friends_count' ORDER BY id DESC))[1]::int) AS friends_count
       FROM daily_statistics st
      GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY max(id) DESC
      )totalFriends
```

Comment: I get: `ERROR:  function sum(json) does not exist`
`LINE 1: SELECT SUM(friends_count) AS total_friend_counts`

Comment: why you convert friends_count to JSON?

Comment: Hmmm, yea possibly dont need to convert to json

Comment: Yes, just use COUNT() for that than this query works for you.